# Don't show me on other profiles

Tags: google-plus, privacy, profile

I would like to disable showing me on other users' profiles in sidebar in circles.

I am pretty sure there was such option in settings, but I can't find it now. To support my thought i've checked my own circles.

On my own circles page ( https://plus.google.com/u/0/circles ) there is "My Circles (194)"
On my profile ( https://plus.google.com/u/0/106157307077731636106/posts ) there is "In your circles: 166".

So I guess 28 people in my circles decided not be shown on other people's profiles.

Answer (score 1):

If you have added people to your circles using email addresses, and those people do not use Google+, they will not show up as "in your circles" on your profile. This explains the different numbers you see.

I cannot find a way to hide the fact that you are in someone else's circle.